# NHibernate EntityPersister get property info (access attribute)

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm using the persister (`AbstractEntityPersister`/`SingleEntityTablePersister`) to get some information of the mapped entities in NHibernate (keys, types, column names, ...), but now I want to get the access attribute of a property tag of an entity mapping:

```
<property type="byte" name="NoExportarAHost" column="PRO_NOEXPORTARAHOST_BS" access="CustomAccessor, CustomLibrary" />
```

Really I only need to know if the attribute is set or not. Is there any way to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you can get this information from the persister. I had the problem that I wanted to know mapping details and I stopped using the metadata API because it was too high level.

Accessing the NHIbernate configuration provide much more mapping details.

```
foreach (var classMapping in configuration.ClassMappings)
{
  foreach (var property in classMapping.PropertyIterator)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("{0} access={1}",
      property.Name,
      property.PropertyAccessorName);
  }
}
```

Comment: And how I retrieve the Configuration object on runtime? Where I need it I have no access to Configuration instance and I don't find any way to get it...

Comment: You have to keep it from initialization. What kind of problem do you actually have to solve?

Comment: Thanks, I would avoid that, but it seems to be the solution!